# Infinite series involving generalised hypergeometric functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I've recently stumbled into hypergeometric functions while trying to evaluate the integral:

$$
\int \exp \big( x^2 + bx + c \big) {\rm erf} ( x ) \operatorname{d\!}x
$$

Essentially, working from an old post in researchgate [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_an_analytical_solution_for_the_indefinite_integral_expx2erfcxdx) I came up with the following solution (modulo any errors I'll no doubt find shortly after posting, neglecting the integration constants and not paying too much attention to convergence issues at this point):

$$
\begin{align}
\int \exp &\big( x^2 + bx + c \big) {\rm erf} ( x )\operatorname{d\!}x & \\
= 
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^c x^2 \sum_{m=0}^\infty {}_2F_2 \left( 1, 1+\frac{m}{2} ; \frac{3}{2} 2+\frac{m}{2} ; x^2 \right) \frac{(bx)^m}{m!}&
\end{align}
$$

by first expanding the exponential as a power series and then following the same approach as per the link for each term.

However nice as this is (at least to my eyes) now I'm curious as to whether it's possible to take this a step further and remove the summation somehow?  A quick consultation with Gradshteyn and a few days on google gives me a lot of interesting results regarding the properties of hypergeometric functions, some relating to their sums, but nothing that applies to this case to simplify the expression in any meaningful way.

So I'm stumped and somewhat out of my depth - any thoughts or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think you should instead have $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^c x^2 \sum_{m=0}^\infty {}_2F_2 \left(1, 1+\frac{m}{2}; \frac{3}{2}, 2+\frac{m}{2}; x^2 \right) \frac{(bx)^m}{m!(m+2)}$$

Comment: It's arguably more elegant to reverse the order of summation, obtaining $$\frac{2e^cx^2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{i \ge 0}{}_1F_1(2i+2;2i+3;bx) \frac{i!(4x^2)^i}{(2i+2)!}$$

Comment: @PeterTaylor - thanks, but I'm not entirely clear where you've got the factor $(m+2)$ from here.  In my derivation I first subbed out the erf and simplified to get:
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^c \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{2^k}{(2k+1)!!} \int x^{2k+1} e^{bx} dx $$
then expanded the exponential as a power series to obtain:
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^c \sum_{k,m \geq 0} \frac{2^k}{(2k+1)!!} \frac{b^m}{m!} \int x^{2k+1+m} dx $$
did the trivial integral, so
$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^c \sum_{k,m \geq 0} \frac{2^k}{(2k+1)!!} \frac{b^m}{m!} \frac{1}{2k+2+m} x^{2k+2+m} $$
then used the defn of $2F2$ ...

Comment: @PeterTaylor ...so I'm not sure where this factor could come from?  Sorry if I'm being obtuse here.
I like the idea of reversing the order of summation and agree that the result is certainly cleaner, but I guess I'll have to re-consult sources to see if it gets me closer to solving/simplifying out the remaining summation.

Comment: The definition of ${}_2F_2$ requires the first term to be $1$. Set $k=0$ and the term inside the double sum is $\frac{b^m x^{2+m}}{m!(m+2)}$

Comment: Oh, I see - thanks!  Still getting used to the definitions here.

Comment: I haven't managed to find any expression for the integral which doesn't have an (explicit or implicit) double sum, but IMO pulling out a factor of $e^{bx}$ is slightly nicer. That gives $$I = \frac{2e^{bx+c}x^2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{i\ge 0} \sum_{j \ge 0} \frac{(-bx)^j (2x)^{2i} i!}{(j+2i+2)!} = \frac{2e^{bx+c}x^2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{m \ge 0} {}_2F_2(1, 1; \tfrac{m+3}{2}, \tfrac{m+4}{2}; x^2) (-bx)^m$$

Comment: It also allows a form where at least we only have one *infinite* sum: $$I = \frac{2e^{bx+c}x^2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{(-bx)^m}{(m+2)!} \sum_{i=0}^{m/2} \left(\frac{4}{b^2}\right)^{i} i!$$

Comment: Having thought about it the final form is probably most practical as at some point I will need to implement this.
I'm still curious if the integral corresponds to a "known" function but for practical purposes I'm thinking I'll just implement a Taylor approximation.  At first glance $I$ looks roughly exponential-like in behaviour (for $b=2$ the finite sum follows [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/sum-k-1-2-3-cdots-n-is-there-a-generic-formula-for-this), so the terms in the infinite sum should die off quickly enough).
Thanks for the help!